# XSLT document() function with escaped chars in file name

Tags: file, xslt, escaping, document, chars

Am parsing XML with file names with escaped characters.  This is the file name on the server:
**Account-V%29%27%22%3B%3A%3E.layout**

When I apply the document function, it is automatically transforming the escaped characters.

```
`<xsl:apply-templates select="document('Account-V%29%27%22%3B%3A%3E.layout')/Layout"/>
```

The above yields an error as it cannot find this file on the server:
**Account-V)'";:>.layout**

Is there way to tell the document() function to not transform the escaped chars in the file?  I tried wrapping this around variables but it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using XSLT 2.0, try using `encode-for-uri()`

```
select="document(encode-for-uri('Account-V%29%27%22%3B%3A%3E.layout'))/Layout"
```

Answer (score 0):

The way that the URI you pass to the document() function gets dereferenced is in many ways implementation-defined, and many XSLT processors give you some control over it, for example by allowing you to supply a user-written URIResolver.

So I don't think the question can be answered without knowing your XSLT processor.

Comment: Hi Michael, this is Apache Xalan running on tomcat.  OS developing on windows, will run on linux in production.  Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Found a workaround, which works.  Isn't the prettiest, but before performing the XSLT, do a string in Java to replace such as `fileNames.replace("%","%25")`  This forces the document() function to escape the percent sign to a percent, which generates the correct file name on the server.  So %252E becomes %2E after the document function.  Going to leave unanswered for a day or two to see if anybody has something better.

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround, which works. Isn't the prettiest, but before performing the XSLT, do a string in Java to replace such as fileNames.replace("%","%25") This forces the document() function to escape the percent sign to a percent, which generates the correct file name on the server.